# sort my database data

Tags: php, sql, sorting

I have a database table like this

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <th>no</th>
   <th>name</th>
   <th>income</th>
   <th>work</th>
   <th>score</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>alan</td>
   <td>US 100</td>
   <td>Designer</td>
   <td>30%</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>lara</td>
   <td>US 100</td>
   <td>Doctor</td>
   <td>34%</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>foong</td>
   <td>US 100</td>
   <td>Teacher</td>
   <td>7%</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>Rose</td>
   <td>US 50</td>
   <td>Waitress</td>
   <td>55%</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>Jack</td>
   <td>US 30</td>
   <td>Programmer</td>
   <td>50%</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>6</td>
   <td>jeff</td>
   <td>US 3</td>
   <td>Lawyer</td>
   <td>90%</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>7</td>
   <td>elson</td>
   <td>US 2000</td>
   <td>Footballer</td>
   <td>60%</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>8</td>
   <td>steve</td>
   <td>US 22</td>
   <td>chef</td>
   <td>10%</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>9</td>
   <td>albert</td>
   <td>US 35</td>
   <td>Admin</td>
   <td>80%</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>10</td>
   <td>warnock</td>
   <td>US 5</td>
   <td>Technicer</td>
   <td>1%</td>
 </tr>
 <table>
```

then I want show the result on the table is Top 5 Score only
but my table is sort by income column.

I use this string to query:

```
 SELECT * FROM table ORDER by score DESC, income ASC LIMIT 0,5
```

but my result is sort by score not income.

I want the table is sort by income with top 5 score only

any idea on this?

thanks for advance.

Comment: That's not a database table, that's an HTML table.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Do you want to be able to dynamically rearrange the table on the page via javascript, or is this actually something in a database like your tags would suggest?

Comment: If you already `ORDER` and `LIMIT` the query, then the problem lies with your output processing / table draw logic. You need to show some code there or explain the data flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just treat your initial result set as a sub-query of one in which you sort your final results by income:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER by score DESC, income ASC LIMIT 0,5 
    ) t
ORDER BY income
```

Answer (score 1):

i think your asking how to limit the results sent back from the sql?

put `ORDER by score LIMIT 0,5` at the end of your query

EDIT:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER by score,income DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: Note that not all SQL dialects use that specific `LIMIT` syntax.  If this doesn't work for you, there's a good chance you're using Oracle or MSSQL.

Comment: and also making us helpers decrypt your question makes it harder to answer ;p

Comment: @Lawrence You shall be rewarded in your afterlife. Now get back to decrypting!

Comment: SELECT * from stackoverflow WHERE questions="PHP" ORDER by date LIMIT 1 ;p

Comment: Yes, I did. But is not the result I want to echo with php

Comment: Yes, I did. But not work. The result is sort by income but the score is not top 5. Thanks for your helping.

Comment: did you try switching it so its SELECT * FROM table ORDER by score,income DESC LIMIT 0,5 it will sort by importance so the first order by is more important then the next and so on...

Answer (score 0):

If you what to show the top 5 score you have to sort the table with 'score' not with income. You can use LIMIT 0,5 to list the top 5 into the table.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to use data return from sql query then put 
**ORDER BY score LIMIT 0, 5** 
at end of your sql query.

Or if you want to sort the data in HTML table, you should do that manaually.

Best of Luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a unique column on your table if yes you may try this.

```
SELECT t2.* 
 FROM (SELECT 
              uniqueId, score 
         FROM yourTable 
        ORDER BY score DESC 
        LIMIT  0,5) as t1
  INNER JOIN yourTable t2 
     ON t2.uniqueId = t1.uniqueId 
  ORDER BY t2.income ASC;
```

Try to execute the query first on your SQL browser to see if the results are correct.

Note: if score is not a numeric data type or if it is a char, this will sort alphabetically. So 10 is came before 2 in ascending order. You can put score + 0 in case of this, I have not yet try this to other data type.

One more thing using LIMIT 0,5 will only get 5 rows. Then base on your question you want to display the top five score. So in case you have a 10 rows with same score and it is the top score the other five will not included.

Ex. 15 person with a score of: 10,9,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,4,4,4,3,1 in my point of view all the person with a score greater than 4 is in the top 5. So LIMIT 0,5 is not the way in case of this. I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER by score DESC, income ASC LIMIT 0,5`

Maybe you should write this:

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER by income ASC, score DESC LIMIT 0,5`